# DEL key not triggered on Access Form (Textbox KeyUp Event)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working on a code that simultaneous updates a formatted textbox while typing in an unformatted textbox (having the same DB field).

```
Private Sub help_text_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Dim lngPos As Long
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 8, 46, 32, KeyCode >= 48 And KeyCode <= 111
            lngPos = Me.help_text.SelStart
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
            Me.help_text_formatted.Requery
            Me.help_text.SelStart = lngPos
    End Select
 End Sub
```

Still working on the key recognition, and maybe I will change the code in updating the textboxes every x seconds in stead of the KeyUp event. However, I noticed that the vbKeyDelete key (46) is triggered only when no text is selected in the textbox. KeyUp is triggered when deleting a selection with the vbKeyBack (8) key. Anyone knows how I can trigger the KeyUp event when deleting a selection with the vbKeyDelete key?

Art.

Comment: Have you set the `Key Preview` property on your form to `Yes`?

Comment: No I did not, thx for the tip. However, that did make things only worse in updating both fields. Call it impatience, but I've parked this for now in creating a double view form solution. For now I made a toggle selection which enables the user to switch views between acTextFormatHTMLRichText and acTextFormatPlain for a TextBox.